# Fourier Analysis an Introduction Chapter 3 Exercise17

Tags: fourier-analysis

17. If $f$ is a bounded monotonic function on $[-\pi,\pi]$, then

$$\hat {f} (n)=O(1/|n|).$$

[Hint: One may assume that $f$ is increasing, and say $|f| \le M.$ First check that the Fourier coefficients of the charateristic function of $[a,b]$ satisfy $O(1/|n|).$ Now show that a sum of the form
$$\sum_{k=1}^{N}\alpha_{k}\chi_{[a_k,a_k+1]}(x)$$
with $-\pi=a_1<a_2\ ...<a_N<a_{N+1}=\pi$ and $-M \le \alpha_{1} \le ... \le\alpha_{N}\le M$ has Fourier coefficients that are $O(1/|n|)$ uniformly in $N$. Summing by parts one gets a telescopic sum $\sum(\alpha_{k+1}-\alpha_{k})$ which can be bounded by $2M.$ Now approximate by the function of the above type.]

I don't really know how to calculate:
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\alpha_{k}\chi_{[a_k,a_k+1]}(x)e^{-inx}dx$$
Since I don't know what charateristic function is used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This characteristic function is just the function that takes value $1$ on $[a_k,a_{k+1}]$. The $\alpha_k$ are just constants.
We are able to interchange sum and integral and it is a finite sum and integral.

The limits of each integral will now be $a_k$ and $a_{k+1}$. The rest is up to you! It will be an integral of the exponential function, that is where the $\frac{1}{|n|}$ comes from.

Also, the idea here is you've proved the statement for simple functions (i.e. weighted sums of characteristics), which you would then extend to monotonic functions.

Comment: Is It the same as the indicator function?

Comment: yes that's the one

Comment: I am just confused, because characteristic function in convex analysis is 0 when x is in $[a_k, a_(k+1)]$, and positive infinity everywhere else.

Comment: Ah I see, in Fourier and measure theory it's going to be an indicator